# Is there a best time of day and day of the week to book affordable flight tickets?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I think it is safe to say that *flying* on the weekend is probably going to be more expensive than during the week. Releated: [Are there certain days of the week or weeks in a month (barring major holidays) that are generally cheapest for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3430/are-there-certain-days-of-the-week-or-weeks-in-a-month-barring-major-holidays)

I am also not asking about [The release date of the (cheap) airline tickets for a given day](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14559/the-release-date-of-the-cheap-airline-tickets-for-a-given-day) which talks about getting the first available tickets.

I am curious about *booking*, specifically, about tickets which were already available. Is there a specific time and day of the week which is the cheapest to book during?

I only ask because I saw an interview once where it was implied that the bookings held for the week which were not actually booked are released at a certain point. This person had said theirs were released Tuesday at noon EST and that the resulting increase in available bookings dropped prices compared to the previous day.

Is there any truth to this? Is there a best time of the week to book (as in actually purchase the tickets, not as in the arrival time/date)?

Comment: @MarkMayo - I did search for the question before posting, but I guess I missed that one. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries, there are a lot of similar wording ones, I knew it was in there but still took a while to find :)

Comment: Flying on week-end is not necessarily more expensive. I often see than Friday night, Saturday morning and Sunday afternoon/night are expensive but Sunday morning flights often are not (presumably because you can't use such a flight for a week-end break).